# How to change first word of the email address to upper case in python

Tags: python

I have a string of email addresses in lower case.

```
s = 'aaa@xxx.com bbb@yyy.com ccc@zzz.com'
```

I need output as shown below:

```
Output: AAA@xxx.com BBB@yyy.com CCC@zzz.com
```

The code:

```
s = 'aaa@xxx.com bbb@yyy.com ccc@zzz.com'
b = s.split(' ')
c = ''
for i in b:
     a = (i[:3].upper())+i[4:]
     c = c+' '+a
print(c)
```

In the above code I split the string and used slicing inside the for loop.
How can I achieve this without the slicing operator?

Comment: First word? Would that be everything before the `@` sign? In an email one.word@example.com would you capitalize one or one.word?

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.sub` with a lambda callback function:

```py
s = 'aaa@xxx.com bbb@yyy.com ccc@zzz.com'
output = re.sub(r'\b\w+(?=@)', lambda x: x.group().upper(), s)
print(output)  # AAA@xxx.com BBB@yyy.com CCC@zzz.com
```

This approach matches the leading word name of each email address, which is then passed to a callback function via a lambda expression.  The callback then calls `upper()` on the email name.

Comment: A great website to test regexes is regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

This code will upper case everything before the `@` in the email addresses:

```py
s = 'aaa@xxx.com bbb@yyy.com ccc@zzz.com one.word@example.com'
b = s.split(' ')
c = []
for e in b:
    e=e.split('@')
    e = e[0].upper()+'@'+e[1]
    c.append(e)
c = ' '.join(c)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
AAA@xxx.com BBB@yyy.com CCC@zzz.com ONE.WORD@example.com
```

and this can be further reduced to two list comprehensions:

```py
s = 'aaa@xxx.com bbb@yyy.com ccc@zzz.com one.word@example.com'
b = [e.split('@') for e in s.split(' ')]
c = ' '.join([e[0].upper()+'@'+e[1] for e in b])
print(c)
```